# Gradually fade to colour using JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a rectangle gradually change its colour (fade) from yellow to white using Javascript after a button is pressed. Sadly my code does not work. Could you help me figure out what is wrong with the code and how to fix it?

I have just begun studying Javascript. Sorry, if this question is stupid. Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas> // create canvas to work with

<button onclick="fade(ctx)">Change the colour!</button>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); //set context
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100); // draw a rectangle
ctx.stroke(); // with border
ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF00"; // fill with yellow
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100); 

function fade(ctx) { // fade function responsible for changing colour

 var dom = getElementById(ctx), level = 1; // new object based on rectangle object, initial iterator is set to 1

 function step() { // inner step function
   var h = level.toString(16);
   dom.fillStyle = '#FFFF' + h + h; // construct a new colour using h variable

   if (level < 15) {
     level += 1;
     setTimeout(step, 100); // do this after every 100 ms
   }

  }

  setTimeout(step, 100);
}

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you don't use CSS for this ?

Comment: I am trying to study Javascript and would like to learn how to work with inner functions and timeouts. I am not sure how changing colour gradually can be done using CSS.

Comment: Only CSS here : http://codepen.io/impressivewebs/pen/zohgt

Comment: @SteevePitis thank you. I did not know this trick with CSS before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it with your code though. You are passing the context into the function already so no need for the `getElementById(ctx)` bit. In fact that will give you an error so remove that line from your code. Instead directly set the fillStyle on the ctx variable like this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFF' + h + h;
```

and you also need to redraw the rectangle, so add this line:

```
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
```

after you set the colour. And that will do it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I did not quite get how exactly to get rid of getElementById(ctx), as I think, I need to add 'level' property to the object anyway. Based on your response I tried to make the following changes, but it still does not work for me. Probably I did not quite understand what changes you suggested to be made: [link]http://pastebin.com/mBSq8Rum (http://pastebin.com/mBSq8Rum)

Comment: So just remove the declaration of the dom variable, you still need the level variable. That line should then be: `var level = 1;` Otherwise code looks correct.

Comment: Great! I made the changes and it worked! Thank you very much! [http://pastebin.com/kyTAktTn](http://pastebin.com/kyTAktTn)